# I want to create a line under a line in a QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I want to place a line on a specific place in a QPlainTextEdit (C++)
When doing it this way:

```
     QPainter p(viewport());
     p.setPen(QColor("red"));
     p.drawLine( 0, 0, 300, lines.at(i)/5);
```

The line is positioned statically on the view, even when scrolling. That is of course because it is on the viewport. I want to paint it on the same view as the text appears. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to paint the red line on the height of a certain text line (`QTextBlock` in Qt)? If so, take a look at the [line number tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-codeeditor.html). Look for the function `void CodeEditor::lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)` at the bottom of the page, where they calculate the height to draw the line numbers. You could modify this function to calculate the position of your line in the `PlainTextEdit`.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question? Qtherwise, if you have figured it out yourself please answer your own question, so that other users can learn from your solution.

Comment: Sorry, I were not aware of an answer  here:-( I have not tried the solution and I kinda' gave up on it :-(